# Julia only imports names from first homemade Module

Tags: module, julia

I have made two modules in Julia. One is for plotting graphs of trees structures, and one is for estimating entropy from simbolic secuences. 
The first one has this first lines:

```
  module ArbolGrafosTikz

using LightGraphs, TikzGraphs

abstract type LabelledDiGraph
end

export LabelledTree, Nodo, Subarbol, Arbol,
       walk_tree, walk_tree!, tikz_representation

struct LabelledTree <: LabelledDiGraph
    g::DiGraph
    labels::Vector{Any}
end
```

etcetera.
The second one has this header:

```
module EntropySymb

using Base.Iterators

export simboliza, problock, ncartprod, issubvec, allprobsn


function simboliza(x, delta=epsi)
    # funcion que pasa floats a tres simbolos.
    result=0
    if x>delta
```

etcetera.

In my main program I have the first lines as thus:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH,".")
include("EntropySymb.jl")
include("ArbolGrafosTikz.jl")
using ArbolGrafosTikz
using EntropySymb
```

but I can only have direct access to the names of objects in ArbolGrafosTikz 
directly, for EntropySymb I have to use the name prefixed with the module, or Julia REPL doesn't seem to know about them.
Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you first `include` the files, which already loads the modules into `Main` so that `Main.EntropySymb` exists. This makes the subsequent import statement `using EntropySymb` return an error

```
ERROR: importing EntropySymb into Main conflicts with an existing identifier
```

If you already add the current directory (or the directory that contains the modules) to `LOAD_PATH`, you do not need the calls to `include` in order to import the module with `using` or `import`. You can simply write

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, ".")
using ArbolGrafosTikz
using EntropySymb
```

If you want to use `include` instead you should use `using` with `Main.ModuleName` or `.ModuleName` to bring the exported names into scope.

```
include("EntropySymb.jl")
include("ArbolGrafosTikz.jl")
using .ArbolGrafosTikz
using .EntropySymb
```

---

Note that you should also face the issue for the first module but I guess the reason why you do not is because the code is run in somewhat different order than the one given in the question or you did not actually run the first `include` statement. Maybe try the same code in a new session to reproduce the issue for the first module, as well.

Comment: Okey, you're right... but it is weird. A week ago, if I didn't put the "include" statement, Julia claimed that It could not find the module, even when the PATH was corrected....

Comment: @wpkzz It is hard to tell what caused your problem earlier, but if you work in a REPL setting, you might accidentally load some file/module before and this would affect your current session and hence the error. Btw, you may want to consider using `pwd()` to get the current working directory instead of `"."` while specifying the path.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the difference between `using` and `import`. `using MyModule` brings `MyModule` into scope, but `import MyModel` brings all exported names.